# where to report a scam done by a forex broker?

Tags: investing

How and where to report a scam done by bisazzamarket.com, a forex broker that claim s to have a USA MSB regulatory number?  they used a MT4 platform to change my initial purchse price and closed my trading deal without my knowledge.  it made me lost about $17,000 USD.

Comment: https://www.nfa.futures.org/registration-membership/who-has-to-register/rfed.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear this from you. Check this website for more information on how to get some help.

https://www.cftc.gov/LearnAndProtect/AdvisoriesAndArticles/fraudadv_forex.html

Hope this helps.

Abdy Sajous